# How to use single quotes in i18n in Playframework2?

Tags: java, internationalization, playframework, playframework-2.0

While working on a French app (french language is full of single quotes), I needed to use i18n with single quotes and many other accentuated chars.

So here is an extract of my `messages.fr-FR` file :

```
some.key=C'est la vie!
```

And here is the output :

```
Cest la vie!
```

How can I use strings containing single quotes in my messages? Already tried those :

```
some.key=C\'est la vie! --> C\est la vie!
some.key="C'est la vie!" --> "Cest la vie!"
```

---

**EDIT** : Thanks to the link [KDavid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1594880/kdavid) gave I was able to find the solution. You have to double single-quote.

```
C''est la vie! --> C'est la vie!
```

Comment: According to [an hold post][1] [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495776/should-i-use-java-text-messageformat-for-localised-messages-without-placeholders you should use \u2019s for single quote.

Comment: None of these worked. `&quot;` was esacaped as `&amp;quot;` and `\u2019` is displayed as is. But I found another solution in the post, you linked : double quoting. If you answer the question, I'll accept yours ;)

Comment: Ooops. looks like I 'stolen' accept promise from @KDavid - excuse me ;) of course if you'll switch it to him I won't mind :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

prefix the single quote with... single quote (so just use two single quotes):

```
some.key=C''est la vie!
```