# i18n binding not working when there is single quote in text

Tags: sapui5

I am working on a UI5 project, and I use i18n in my controller,

like this:

```
MessageBox.error(Utils.i18n("JOB_DELETE_FAILED_MSG", sName), {
    details: "Some error message"
});
```

and in my i18n file:

```
JOB_DELETE_FAILED_MSG=Couldn't delete job "{0}". Please contact your system administrator.
```

but the message displayed in the message box becomes:

> Couldnt delete job "{0}". Please contact your system administrator.

the binding seems not working.

But when I delete the `'` in "couldn't" in the i18n file, the binding worked again

> Couldnt delete job "job1". Please contact your system administrator.

Could you please tell me what is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`JOB_DELETE_FAILED_MSG=Couldn''t delete job "{0}". Please contact your system administrator`

Similar question here: [How to use single quotes in i18n in Playframework2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070093/how-to-use-single-quotes-in-i18n-in-playframework2)

As an escape sequence starts with a backslash (\) that informs the JavaScript interpreter that the next character is a special character.

Single quote (`) is an escape indicator in i18n.

**But for i18n which is directly bind in XML view, escape is not need which I don't know why.**